# WCF Service Check for a Client Timeout

Tags: wcf, timeout

Is there a way in a WCF service to catch a client timeout I need to run some special logic on a client timeout.

I have not found any sources indicating a WCF service can check if a client timeout through service side Error Handling, Etc... if you require more information let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that needs to be cleaned up in your service, should be cleaned up regardless of whether there was a client timeout, a client disconnection, or an exception in the service.

Do your cleanup in the `finally` block of a `try/finally`, or, if you clean up by calling the `Dispose` method of an `IDisposable` object, then use `using` blocks.

Comment: I asked the question incorrectly I changed the text - Is there a way in a WCF service to catch a client timeout I need to run some special logic on a client timeout. It's not cleanup code rather some code I have to run only on a client timeout

Comment: No, there is no way even for WCF to _know_ that the client timed out. In fact, what do you mean when you say "client timeout"?

Comment: I didn't think there was. I mean you set the service endpoint timeout, when a client calls a service if the request runs longer then the specified timeout for the endpoint the client receives a timeout exception. Can the WCF service detect the timeout exception. If not I will just mark this as the answer and mark closed. Thanks

Comment: No, there's no way for the server to see the exception. Consider that the client may time out before successfully connecting to the server.